# How to only re-render the updated elements of array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, rendering

```
function Domain({ props }) {
  return (
    <div className="Domain">
      <div className="charts_uni">
        {props?.map((domain, idx) => {
          return (
            <ul key={`key${idx}`}>
              <h3>{`${domain.key}`}</h3>
              <div>
                <li>
                  avg
                  <br />
                  {domain.content[4].avg}
                </li>
                <li>
                  median
                  <br />
                  {domain.content[4].median}
                </li>
                <li>
                  mode
                  <br />
                  {domain.content[4].mode}
                </li>
                <li>
                  min
                  <br />
                  {domain.content[4].min}
                </li>
                <li>
                  max
                  <br />
                  {domain.content[4].max}
                </li>
              </div>
              <ChartsUni
                key={domain.key}
                objKey={domain.key}
                arr={domain.content[3]}
              />
            </ul>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="charts_multi">
        {props.map((domain1) =>
          props.map((domain2) => {
            if (domain1.key < domain2.key) {
              return (
                <ChartsMulti
                  key={`${domain1.key}+${domain2.key}`}
                  key1={domain1.key}
                  key2={domain2.key}
                  arr1={domain1.content[3]}
                  arr2={domain2.content[3]}
                />
              );
            }
          })
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Domain;
```

'props' is an array from parent component of this Domain component.
When props updates (add or delete elements) all elements in Domain component re-renders.
How to avoid re-render?

[image]

The d3 graphs all re-renders, so performance goes bad.
Please give me a hint.
Thank you.

Comment: from the code you posted all components in you're Domain component are using props so if props changes everything will update, if you do have a component not using props that you want shouldnt rerender useMemo hook will work